# Adjusting Edge Size for Only Some Edges in Gephi

Tags: gephi

I'm working with a graph that has edge weights ranging from 1-3 and while the edges of weights 2 & 3 are clear, the edges of weight 1 are very small. If anyone has any tips on how to increase the size of just the smalles edges without affecting the others that'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Using the slider which increases all edge sizes at the same time doesn't work because the edges of weight 3 get massive before the small ones are visible and changing the weights to be 1.75, 2.0, and 3.0 didn't work either because it seems that Gephi sizes them relatively.